# Could NOT find Boost in when specific boost root

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

Here is my CMakeList.txt file:

```
set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS ON)
set(BOOST_ROOT $ENV{HOME}/Downloads/boost_1_60_0)
set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR ${BOOST_ROOT})
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR ${BOOST_ROOT}/bin.v2/libs)
find_package(Boost 1.60.0 COMPONENTS chrono context filesystem graphParallel iOStreams locale mpi program_options regex serialization signals system thread timer wave date_time graph math random test exception)
message("Boost_LIBRARIES:${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
include_directories(${BOOST_INCLUDEDIR})
```

Here is my boost directory structure:

```
roroco@roroco-Zhaoyang-K49 ~/Downloads/boost_1_60_0 $ lsa
total 708
drwx------  10 roroco roroco   4096 Feb 16 23:10 .
drwx------  20 roroco roroco  24576 Feb 16 23:10 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 roroco roroco 263256 Feb 16 23:01 b2
drwxr-xr-x   4 roroco roroco   4096 Feb 16 23:10 bin.v2
-rwxr-xr-x   1 roroco roroco 263256 Feb 16 23:01 bjam
drwxr-xr-x 106 roroco roroco  12288 Dec 14 22:12 boost
-rw-r--r--   1 roroco roroco    850 Dec 14 10:30 boost-build.jam
-rw-r--r--   1 roroco roroco  21920 Dec 14 10:30 boostcpp.jam
-rw-r--r--   1 roroco roroco    989 Dec 14 10:30 boost.css
-rw-r--r--   1 roroco roroco   6308 Dec 14 10:30 boost.png
-rw-r--r--   1 roroco roroco   2477 Dec 14 10:30 bootstrap.bat
-rw-r--r--   1 roroco roroco    909 Feb 16 23:01 bootstrap.log
-rwxr-xr-x   1 roroco roroco  10631 Dec 14 10:30 bootstrap.sh
drwx------   7 roroco roroco   4096 Dec 14 22:12 doc
-rw-r--r--   1 roroco roroco    769 Dec 14 10:30 index.htm
-rw-r--r--   1 roroco roroco   5472 Dec 14 10:30 index.html
-rw-r--r--   1 roroco roroco    291 Dec 14 10:30 INSTALL
-rw-r--r--   1 roroco roroco  10779 Dec 14 10:30 Jamroot
drwx------ 117 roroco roroco   4096 Dec 14 22:12 libs
-rw-r--r--   1 roroco roroco   1338 Dec 14 10:30 LICENSE_1_0.txt
drwxr-xr-x   4 roroco roroco   4096 Dec 14 10:30 more
-rw-r--r--   1 roroco roroco    928 Feb 16 23:01 project-config.jam
-rw-r--r--   1 roroco roroco    976 Feb 16 22:28 project-config.jam.1
-rw-r--r--   1 roroco roroco   1000 Feb 16 22:29 project-config.jam.2
-rw-r--r--   1 roroco roroco    928 Feb 16 22:51 project-config.jam.3
-rw-r--r--   1 roroco roroco    928 Feb 16 23:00 project-config.jam.4
-rw-r--r--   1 roroco roroco   2608 Dec 14 10:30 rst.css
drwxr-xr-x   3 roroco roroco   4096 Feb 16 22:28 stage
drwxr-xr-x   2 roroco roroco   4096 Dec 14 10:30 status
drwxr-xr-x  10 roroco roroco   4096 Dec 14 10:30 tools
-rw-r--r--   1 roroco roroco     30 Feb 16 22:59 user-config.jam
roroco@roroco-Zhaoyang-K49 ~/Downloads/boost_1_60_0 $ lsa bin.v2
total 28
drwxr-xr-x  4 roroco roroco 4096 Feb 16 23:10 .
drwx------ 10 roroco roroco 4096 Feb 16 23:10 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 roroco roroco 7957 Feb 16 23:10 config.log
drwxr-xr-x 27 roroco roroco 4096 Feb 16 23:17 libs
-rw-r--r--  1 roroco roroco 3030 Feb 16 23:10 project-cache.jam
drwxr-xr-x  3 roroco roroco 4096 Feb 16 23:10 standalone
lrwxrwxrwx  1 roroco roroco   19 Feb 16 23:10 test-symlink -> test-symlink-source
-rw-r--r--  1 roroco roroco    0 Feb 16 23:10 test-symlink-source
```

**update**
the `cmake` output is:

```
 in /tmp/home/roroco/Dropbox/cs/ro-c
cmake /home/roroco/Dropbox/cs/ro-c 
-- Could NOT find Boost
-- Could NOT find Boost
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/home/roroco/Dropbox/cs/ro-c
```

Comment: When you specify `BOOST_ROOT`, no needs to specify other tuning variables (`BOOST_INCLUDEDIR` and `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR`). What output of `find_package` call?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I update my output

Comment: @hucmarcot which version of cmake you using? Try add Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS "1.60.0" "1.60" - this will help if FindBoost.cmake, packaged with cmake, does not have never version of boost installed.

Answer (score 0):

when i `set(Boost_DEBUG 1)` in cmake, the output show I add non-exist components in find_package, I can find all component names from /home/roroco/Downloads/boost_1_60_0/stage/lib, so the new find_package is

```
find_package(Boost 1.60.0 COMPONENTS atomic filesystem math_c99l program_options thread random timer chrono graph math_c99 regex type_erasure math_tr1 container locale math_tr1f serialization unit_test_framework context log math_tr1l log_setup signals wave coroutine system wserialization prg_exec_monitor date_time math_c99f test_exec_monitor exception)
```